# ng-options with array of objects linking to an ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, ng-init

I am creating a select with `ng-options` that loops through an array of objects linking to an `ng-init`. However, the problem is, it has to pass the correct variable through `ng-change` as well.

Right now the code below will make `ng-init` work and pick the right option on load. However, when the options are selected it doesn't pass the id to the `ng-change`

```
<select name="baddress" ng-init="autoship.baddress_id = address.id || addresses[0]" 
ng-model="autoship.baddress_id" 
ng-change="setter('baddress', autoship, address.id)" 
ng-options="address as address.address + ' ' + address.address2 + ' ' + address.city + ', ' + address.state + ' ' + address.zipcode for address in addresses" ></select>
```

By adding `.id` to `address` in the beginning of the `ng-options`, the `ng-change` works perfectly but it leaves the select drop down empty on load.

```
<select name="baddress" 
ng-init="autoship.baddress_id = address.id || addresses[0]" 
ng-model="autoship.baddress_id" 
ng-change="setter('baddress', autoship, address.id)" 
ng-options="address.id as address.address + ' ' + address.address2 + ' ' + address.city + ', ' + address.state + ' ' + address.zipcode for address in addresses" ></select>
```

Comment: *"linking to an ng-init"* ... this is not what `ng-init` is for (see docs). Use controller to handle business logic like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adresses[0] will be the whole address object in this line:

```
ng-init="autoship.baddress_id = address.id || addresses[0]"
```

In order to only keep the id, I think you should change it to:

```
ng-init="autoship.baddress_id = address.id || addresses[0].id"
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much I will accept answer once it lets me.

Comment: This makes the fallback work. Which is great but now I am realizing that the first part just never worked at all. I think @charlietfl comment is correct.

Comment: @lettman1 So you can just init this variable in your controller: `$scope.autoship.baddress_id = whatever;`